# How do you make a google script run on whichever google sheet is open?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made an app to insert data into a google spreadsheet. Usually you set the url of the google spreadsheet that the script is going to perform the actions specified in it.

```
function doGet(e){
var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("your google spread sheet url");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
```

Instead of setting a permanent url, i wanted the google script to perform the actions on a google spreadsheet that is open at that moment. This way if i create a new google spreadsheet, i don't have to change the url in the script 
 to add data since the app script will run on whichever spreadsheet is open.
Initially i tried this but it didn't work

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
```

When i used getActiveSpreadSheet and deployed it as a web app(testing the code) it gave me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null. (line 4, file "Code")

Edited.
I tried this but wont work.

```
function doGet(e){
var newUrl = e.parameter.newurl
var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl([newurl]);
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
```

Comment: If you had the app open the spreadsheet, then record what spreadsheet is open, then the app would have a record of what spreadsheet is open.  Apps Script can't know what spreadsheet is open.  The `getActiveSpreadsheet` method only works for script bound to a spreadsheet, or from a script installed as an Add-on.

Comment: You could put a contained script inside of every spreadsheet that communicates with a standalone webapp telling it what spreadsheet url is and letting the webapp know that your open and then you can respond by loading your data.

Comment: how do you do that

Comment: You create a script and run it in the onOpen() trigger.

Comment: I've never actually done anything like this before but I was thinking that you might be able to use URLFetch to communicate with the webapps doGet() by passing it parameters in the Query String.

Comment: do you have a piece of code that could give me an idea how it will work

Comment: I've tried changing it to the part above under edited